# Troubleshooting SQL Timeout Expired

Tags: c#, sql, linq, nhibernate

My C# application is currently throwing lots of the below exceptions:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
> the operation or the server is not responding.  This failure occurred
> while attempting to connect to the routing destination.

I am using linq queries and NHibernate.

I am having difficulty troubleshooting this as the exception does not occur every time the query is ran. If I take the query and run it directly on SSMS it seems to run very quickly.

The timeout exceptions only appear to occur when ran against one table in the database.

I know I am able to increase the query timeout but I would like to resolve the root cause of the issue. I have a limited knowledge in troubleshooting these issues so what are the next steps I need to take to determine what the problem is?

Comment: If it's MS SQL Server you can have it run a monitor during a certain period of time, that will analyze queries and suggest improvements. But first, I'd **log** the exact request params that were used, so you can analyze those and maybe find a pattern.

Comment: SSMS always runs quicker than SQLClient.  The SQLClient Class has to pack/unpack data when sending to/from c#.  The error message appears to be a connection issue and not a command timeout.  How long does it take for error to occur?  what is the connection string?  If it is  only occurring for one table the table credentials may not allow you access.

Answer (score 0):

Increase 'Connect Timeout' of your connection string. 60 is a good number.